# Detectar en que elementos no se hizo click

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente código que identifica en cual de los elementos se ha hecho clic, pero de que manera puedo saber, ¿en que elemento no se ha hecho clic?

```js
$('body').on('click', '.container-abd a', function(){
        var element = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(element)
    })
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-abd sticky-top">
      <ul>
        <a href="#ebasic-profile">
          <li><i class='bx bx-layer'></i>Basic</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#security">
          <li><i class='bx bx-shield'></i>Security</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo usando `siblings()` asi:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.container-abd a', function(){
        var element = $(this).attr('href');
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var anchors = parent.find('a');
        var notClicked = [];
        anchors.each(function(i, anchor) {
          if($(anchor).attr('href') != element) {
            notClicked.push($(anchor).attr('href'));
          }
        });
        alert(notClicked)
    })
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-abd sticky-top">
      <ul>
        <a href="#ebasic-profile">
          <li><i class='bx bx-layer'></i>Basic</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#security">
          <li><i class='bx bx-shield'></i>Security</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#tercero">
          <li><i class='bx bx-shield'></i>Tercero</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    </body>
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección con solo 2 elementos, pero al usar más de 2 solo me muestra el #ebasic

Comment: En ese caso puedes usar `each()`, ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, funciona muy bien.